# Какой FrameWork больше подходит для создания Социальной Сети: Spring или Grails?

Tags: spring, java, framework

Главное - скорость разработки.

Comment: с каждым днем вопросы все интереснее и интереснее...

Comment: скороть разработки?)))) для этого вк даем cms свою

Comment: Ну не Spring это точно...

Comment: Grails для социальной сети? Хоть вы и сказали что для вас главное - скорость разработки, но боюсь, что перфоманс вам потом аукнется(вдруг проект взлетит).

Comment: если для малых нужд (универ/школа/компания) - то считаю что не важно, хоть опыта наберетесь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По перформансу - есть кейсы, где Grails работает на сайте с 1,5М пользователей, 80К одновременно пользователей на сайте http://www.clickonero.com.mx/
Если речь идет о нишевой социальной сети, то этого должно быть вполне достаточно (а если не о нишевой, то стоит пересмотреть целесообразность запуска проекта)

Касательно сравнения Grails с Spring MVC: с одной стороны, на Grails очень легко делать прототипы "за человеконеделю" - то же самое на plain Spring будет делаться человекомесяц; при этом в отличие от Roo или GWT эти прототипы хорошо подходят для дальнейшего развития.
С другой стороны, для постоянной работы над большим проектом на Grails в его изучение надо инвестировать время, надо хорошо разбираться, как работают базовые технологии Spring и Hibernate, понимать Groovy, быть готовым читать много материалов по-английски.

Если в команде есть компетентный человек или человек, который готов инвестировать в это свое время, и вы хотите построить современный процесс разработки http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Sky.com-Infrastructure , то в длительной перспективе вы реально выиграете.

Но, к сожалению, на русскоязычных форумах часто встречаются отзывы от желающих получить все, сразу и бесплатно, которые после первого месяца оказываются в ситуации "ничего не работает, мой говнокод без тестов постоянно ломается, ну нафиг эти ваши фрэймворки".

Answer (score 0):

На граилс конешн быстрее, особенно применяя скаффолдинг. Но легче наговнокодить. 
Там применяется немного иная философия с разработке веб приложений ориентированая на доменную модель.

Но без хороших знаний JSP -> Spring + Hibernate -> нельзя прийти к разработке качевственных приложений на Граилс